# Can an Enum be used to provide two values?

Tags: c#-4.0, enums, drawing

For drawing filled shapes like Rectangle, Eclipse need two values width and height (converted from int to float).

There's an enum,

```
Public enum Sizes : int
{
  One=5,
  Two=10,
  Five=10,
  Seven=12,
  Ten=15,      
}
```

In terms of drawing a Square of `One`, should be of width and height of 5. Which is straight forward. However when drawing Oval Shapes and Rectangular shapes above one value isn't sufficient.
Is there a way I could define another float value? So when compared for `Ten`, it can provide 15 for Width and 10 for Height...

Or does it mean, there should be two enums, one for Width and one for Height?

**EDIT to provide more background info:**

There's an UI which allows users to create certain shapes. 
User inputs are: Shape Type (Line, Rectangle, Eclipse), Points, Size (but this size doesn't exactly reflect the size of the shape. e.g. 10 is a capacity. Capacity 10 must draw 15px Width and 10px height Rectangle/Eclipse).
Line doesn't take Size into account as it is drawn using the Points input. The rest of the shapes do take Size into account. So this is where I need to check the Size(capacity) parameter and *issue* the correct Width and Height to be drawn.

Comment: I dont think that enum may be the right construct to model this kind of problem. Even if you somehow get the soltuion for it, I dont think using an Enum would be a right approach in this case

Comment: Indeed, that would be a *very* strange use of enums. Why don't you just have values of type `float`?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's indeed strange and odd to achieve from Enums... I was just trying to reduce/not use if/else at all. Perhaps I gotta write an *read-made* object which will emit the two float properties width and height for a given parameter. BTW Could you elaborate a bit on *`Why don't you just have values of type float?`*

Comment: @bonCodigo: Why would you need if/else? Basically, it's entirely unclear what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have just updated the question with more info. There might be an easier way to do it - I bet. I just want to write optimized code.

Comment: So basically, for each Size/ShapeType pair, you want an "actual" size, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet precisely. But there's more to the combination of Size/ShapeType, such as Colour etc. But for getting the concept into work, yes Size/ShapeType to "Actual" would be ideal.

Comment: So either you could have a `Dictionary<Tuple<ShapeType, SizeEnum>, Size>`, or perhaps have a switch statement in each shape. (It depends where you want the mapping data, really.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Excellent, `Dictionary<Tuple<ShapeType, SizeEnum>, Size>`. This would do. Instead of Switch, I will test out `dictionary linq`. Thanks heaps! That should be the answer,not the comment :)